# Why bumping a question which is dormant while OP is absent for long time

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

My question is about [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/can-i-install-a-diamond-x30a-antenna-on-a-balcony-with-a-metal-rail)

As you can see, it was "bumped" recently

[image]

The following to note from this post:

- Originally posted on 18-July-2017
- User last seen on 25-July-2017

I understand that sometimes posts are "bumped" to see if you can get an answer. This post however has 4 answers (3 good, 1 deleted).

It is unlikely that we would ever get an answer "accepted", as I find it unlikely that the OP will return to accept an answer.

Questions:

- Why would this post be bumped if the OP is absent for a long time ?
- Would it be possile to adjust the "bumping algoritm" not to bump if OP is absent for a long time ?
- Would it be possible to "mark this question as answered" and many similar like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular bump has **successfully served its purpose**.

I just looked at the (public) reputation histories of the answerers there to confirm that the answers *just got upvoted* — before the bump, the two top answers had a score of 0. Only questions with no positive-scoring answers get these bumps.

In general, when you see a question that is bumped, what you can do about it is try to get it a positive-scoring answer — whether that is upvoting an existing answer or writing a new, better one that others can upvote.

Acceptance is not necessary. Acceptance is in general an optional feature — all the systems are designed to work *even if* the asker never returns to accept an answer.

Comment: So the purpose of "bumping" is to get "votes on answers or another answer"... and not "acceptance"... right, got it... thanks

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo The purpose is to get answers voted on — that's what the "may be good or bad … can be reviewed" text in the notice means. Adding an answer is just how to help solve the problem if there is no answer good enough to upvote.

Comment: **"Only questions with no positive-scoring answers get these bumps."** I just learned something *very* useful! Thanks.

Comment: @MikeWaters same here.... learned something new :-)

Comment: Aha, so if I get sick of a question that constantly gets recycled, then all I have to do is to upvote an answer ;)